# PHP: How to implode these array values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have these code:

```
 $arr = array($check);
```

When I try to

```
 echo "<pre>"; 
 die(print_r($arr));
```

it gives me result in the Firebug

```
 <pre>Array
          (
            [0] => Array
             (
               [0] => 2
               [1] => 1
             )

           )
```

Now, I want an output that will give me '2,1'.
How could I do that in PHP? Do I need to use implode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need to implode:

```
echo implode(',', $check);
```

You don't need to put it inside an array:

```
$arr = array($check); // no need
```

Comment: Outer array well tackled! Authority!!

Comment: @DOCASAREL it makes no sense to assign it in an array again

Comment: @DOCASAREL i don't really know what you want at the moment, but answere is exactly what op wants and also describes ops mistake.